# Return the part of the regex that matched

Tags: javascript, regex

In a regular expression that uses `OR` (pipe), is there a convenient method for getting the part of the expression that matched.

Example:

```
/horse|caMel|TORTOISe/i.exec("Camel");
```

returns `Camel`. What I want is `caMel`.

I understand that I could loop through the options instead of using one big regular expression; that would make far more sense. But I'm interested to know if it can be done this way.

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to return the regular expression, not the matched string?

Comment: Based on that example, it returned what matched. You explcitly told the regex to ignore the text's **case** and **camel** matched that. So, it returned the string input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply, no.

Regex matches have to do with your input string and not the text used to create the regular expression.  Note that that text might well be lost, and theoretically is not even necessary.  An equivalent matcher could be built out of something like this:

```
var test = function(str) {
    var text = str.toLowerCase();
    return text === "horse" || text === "camel" || text === "tortoise";
};
```

Another way to think of it is that the compilation of regular expressions can divorce the logic of the function from their textual representation.  It's one-directional.

Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way built-in to the Javascript RegExp object; without changing your expression. The closest you can get is `source` which will just return the entire expression as a string.

Since you know you're expression is a series of `| OR`s, you could capturing groups to figure out which group matched, and combine that with `.source` to find out the contents of that group:

```
var exp = /(horse)|(caMel)|(TORTOISe)/i;
var result = exp.exec("Camel");
var match = function(){
    for(var i = 1; i < result.length; i++){
        if(result[i]){
            return exp.source.match(new RegExp('(?:[^(]*\\((?!\\?\\:)){' + i + '}([^)]*)'))[1];
        }
    }
}();

// match == caMel
```

It is also extremely easy (although somewhat impractical) to write a RegExp engine from scratch would you could technically add that functionality to. It would be much slower than using an actual RegExp object, since the whole engine would have to be interpreted at run-time. It would, however, be able to return exactly the matched portion of the expression for any regular expression and not be limited to one which consists of a series of `| OR`s.

The best way to solve your problem, however, is probably not to use a loop or a regular expression at all, but instead to create an object where you use a canonical form for the key:

```
var matches = {
  'horse': 'horse',
  'camel': 'caMel',
  'tortoise': 'TORTOISe'
};

// Test "Camel"
matches['Camel'.toLowerCase()]; // "caMel"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give the wanted value without looping:

```
var foo, pat, tres, res, reg = /horse|caMel|TORTOISe/i;
foo = reg.exec('Camel');

if (foo) {
    foo = foo[0].replace(/\./g, '\\.');
    pat = new RegExp('\\|' + foo + '\\|', 'i');
    tres = '|' + reg.source + '|';
    res = tres.match(pat)[0].replace(/\|/g, '');
}

alert(res);
```

If there's no match, now you get `undefined`, though it's easy to change to something else.

Comment: That will work for the one test case, but it will fail for something like `/CAmel|caME|horse/i` with the sting "Came" (It will return "CAme" instead of "caME").

Comment: @Paulpro Unfortenately you're right with this. I'm checking, if there's something I can fix, if it can't (or I can't) I'll remove the answer.

Comment: It would also fail if `foo` turned out to be a more complex expression including characters meaningful in regex parsing.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That is also true, but I think that the OP was asking specifically about a RegExp which is just a series of character literals and `| OR`s.

Comment: Teemu, I think `pat = new RegExp('\\b' + foo + '\\b', 'i');` may work. It at least works for the additional test case I provided.

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks, I was just coming to `'\\b'` after tried a complex patterns with `|`.

Comment: Oh yeah, also you forgot to declare `foo` and `pat` with `var`, so they are implicit globals. It would be good to fix that as well.

Comment: But do note that if `reg = /horse|caMel|Mrs Ed|Mr. Ed|TORTOISe/i` and `foo = reg.exec('Mr. Ed')`, you will still alert `Mrs Ed`.  The user would have to decide if this sort of problem is ok.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That might be a fatal error in some conditions ; ). I've fixed the code against it, but it looks like if I try to fix all possible special characters in `foo`, the looped version would be shorter...

Comment: And I'd bet that in five minutes I could come up with another example that would break this version.  That's the trouble with these; you could forever be trying to play catch-up.  I still stand by my original answer; it's essentially impossible.  Although as shown here, it can be done for certain limited subset of pipe-delimited regexes.