# How to return the regex that matches some text?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The answer to Javascript regex question [Return the part of the regex that matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793423/return-the-part-of-the-regex-that-matched) is "No, because compilation destroys the relationship between the regex text and the matching logic."

But Python preserves [Match Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), and `re.groups()` returns the specific group(s) that triggered a match.  It should be simple to preserve the regex text of each group as part of a Match Object and return it, but there doesn't appear to be a call to do so.

```
import re

pat = "(^\d+$)|(^\w+$)|(^\W+$)"
test = ['a', 'c3', '36d', '51', '29.5', '#$%&']
for t in test:
    m = re.search(pat, t)
    s = (m.lastindex, m.groups()) if m else ''
    print(str(bool(m)), s)
```

This returns:

```
True (2, (None, 'a', None))
True (2, (None, 'c3', None))
True (1, ('51', None, None))
False
True (3, (None, None, '#$%&'))
```

The compiler obviously knows that there are three groups in this pattern.  Is there a way to extract the subpattern in each group in a regex, with something like:

```
>>> print(m.regex_group_text)

('^\d+$', '^\w+$', '^\W+$')
```

Yes, it would be possible to write a custom pattern parser, for example to split on '|' for this particular pattern.  But it would be far easier and more reliable to use the re compiler's understanding of the text in each group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the indices are not sufficient and you absolutely need to know the exact *part of the regex*, there is probably no other possibility but to parse the expression's groups on your own.

All in all, this is no big deal, since you can simply count opening and closing brackets and log their indices:

```
def locateBraces(inp):
    bracePositions = []
    braceStack = []
    depth = 0
    for i in range(len(inp)):
        if inp[i] == '(':
            braceStack.append(i)
            depth += 1
        if inp[i] == ')':
            bracePositions.append((braceStack.pop(), i))
            depth -= 1
            if depth < 0:
                raise SyntaxError('Too many closing braces.')
    if depth != 0:
        raise SyntaxError('Too many opening braces.')
    return bracePositions
```

> **Edited:** This dumb implementation only counts opening and closing braces. However, regexes may contain escaped braces, e.g. `\(`, which are
>   counted as regular group-defining braces using this method. You may
>   want to adapt it to omit braces that have an uneven number of
>   backslashes right before them. I leave this issue as a task for you ;)

With this function, your example becomes:

```
pat = "(^\d+$)|(^\w+$)|(^\W+$)"
bloc = locateBraces(pat)

test = ['a', 'c3', '36d', '51', '29.5', '#$%&']
for t in test:
    m = re.search(pat, t)
    print(str(bool(m)), end='')
    if m:
        h = bloc[m.lastindex - 1]
        print(' %s' % (pat[h[0]:h[1] + 1]))
    else:
        print()
```

Which returns:

```
True (^\w+$)
True (^\w+$)
True (^\w+$)
True (^\d+$)
False
True (^\W+$)
```

> **Edited:** To get the list of your groups, of course a simple comprehension would do:
>
> ```
> gtxt = [pat[b[0]:b[1] + 1] for b in bloc]
> ```

Comment: Yes, this completely answers the question if it will work for all regexes.   I didn't think the parser would be that simple.  Thanks!

Comment: There is one flaw: If the regex contains an escaped brace, e.g. `\(`, then this dumb parser would assume it as a regular group-defining brace. Tracking the number of backslashes before each brace makes it a bit less handy...

Answer (score 4):

This may or may not be helpful depending on the problem that you are actually trying to solve ... But python lets you name the groups:

```
r = re.compile('(?P<int>^\d+$)|(?P<word>^\w+$)')
```

From there, when you have a match, you can inspect the `groupdict` to see which groups are present:

```
r.match('foo').groupdict()  # {'int': None, 'word': 'foo'}
r.match('10').groupdict()  # {'int': '10', 'word': None}
```

Of course, this doesn't tell you the exact regular expression associated with the match -- You'd need to keep track of that yourself based on the group name.

If you really want to go beyond this, you probably want something a little more sophisticated than simple regular expression parsing.  In that case, I might suggest something like [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).  Don't let the old-school styling on the website fool you (or the lack of a PEP-8 compliant API) -- the library is actually quite powerful once you get used to it.

Comment: Great idea.  Build the big regex from a dict of {group_name: group_re} in the first place.  I looked in `sre_parse.py`, `sre_compile.py` etc but ran with my tail between my legs ... horrible code in there

Comment: Thanks, but it is just as easy to keep track of the expression for positional (non-named) groups if you're writing the expression yourself.   My question is more along the lines of "read a pattern, return the expressions for groups in that pattern" - named groups don't make that any easier.

Comment: @wim -- I looked at the public interface on the regex objects before I came up with this idea.  There might be something non-public that you could use, but I'm not about to suggest relying on module internal implementation details in an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It will remain up to you to track what regular expressions you are feeding into `re.search`. Something like:

```
import re

patts = {
  'a': '\d+',
  'b': '^\w+',
  'c': '\W+'
}

pat = '^' + '|'.join('({})'.format(x) for x in patts.values()) + '$'
test = ['a', 'c3', '36d', '51', '29.5', '#$%&']
for t in test:
    m = re.search(pat, t)
    if m:
      for g in m.groups():
        for key, regex in patts.iteritems():
          if g and re.search(regex, g):
            print "t={} matched regex={} ({})".format(t, key, regex)
            break
```

Comment: I wound up matching each of the individual patterns separately in a loop.  In the problem that motivated this question I know what they are and don't need to parse a big pattern to extract them.  I haven't measured the speed difference between three small searches and one large one - if it's 3:1 then doing the join at the beginning would definitely be a better approach than looping.